# How to obtain an unknown number of regex matches?

Tags: c++, regex, c++14

I'm trying to find several digits places in a string. I'm able to get only the last one, or a previously specified number of digits:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s("aaabbbccd123456eeffgg");
    std::smatch match;
    std::regex braced_regex("(\\w+)(\\d{2,})(\\w+)");
    std::regex plus_regex("(\\w+)(\\d+)(\\w+)");

    auto printer = [](auto& match) {
            std::ssub_match sub(match);
            std::string match_substring(sub.str());
            std::cout <<  match_substring << '\n';
    };

    std::regex_match(s, match, braced_regex);
    std::cout << "Number of braced matches: " << match.size() << '\n';  
    std::for_each(match.begin(), match.end(), printer);

    std::regex_match(s, match, plus_regex);
    std::cout << "Number of plus matches: " << match.size() << '\n';  
    std::for_each(match.begin(), match.end(), printer);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Number of braced matches: 4
aaabbbccd123456eeffgg
aaabbbccd1234
56
eeffgg
Number of plus matches: 4
aaabbbccd123456eeffgg
aaabbbccd12345
6
eeffgg
```

How can I obtain the whole number sequence, i.e. 123456 from the provided string?

Comment: Note that *regex string* is a good place to use Raw string (C++11): `R"(([a-zA-Z]+)(\d{2,})([a-zA-Z]+))"`

Comment: Just for style: [cleaned up code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd87f7ea341a5f18)

Comment: auto in lambda is c++14, to make this example more like c++11 change `auto& match` to `decltype(*match.begin())& match`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
([a-zA-Z]+)(\\d{2,})([a-zA-Z]+)
```

You can try this.`\w`===`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.So `\w+` will match max it can.So it lets `\d{2,}` have just 2.

or

```
(\\w+?)(\\d{2,})(\\w+)
```

Make the first `\w` non greedy. See [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/qB0jV1/25).

Comment: @SebastianKramer if you want to use it then make it `lazy` by apending `+?` after it

Comment: Why should I make [:alpha:] lazy? Won't it match digit's prefix anyway?

Comment: @SebastianKramer alpha is same as `\w` .So it will again eat up into your digits and you wont get all of it unless you make it lazy

Comment: I believe that [:alnum:] relates to \w (minus underscore), and [:alpha:] is equal to [a-zA-Z], is this correct?

Comment: @SebastianKramer yes you re right.Then `?` is not needed

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that the numbers are considered word parts and get matched with `\w`. I would be tempted to use `\D` meaning **not a digit**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s("aaabbbccd123456eeffgg");
    std::smatch match;
    std::regex plus_regex("(\\D+)(\\d+)(\\D+)");

    auto printer = [](auto& match) {
            std::ssub_match sub(match);
            std::string match_substring(sub.str());
            std::cout <<  match_substring << '\n';
    };

    std::regex_match(s, match, plus_regex);
    std::cout << "Number of plus matches: " << match.size() << '\n';
    std::for_each(match.begin(), match.end(), printer);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Number of plus matches: 4
aaabbbccd123456eeffgg
aaabbbccd
123456
eeffgg
```

Another possibility (depending what you want) is to use `std::regex_search()` which does not try to match the whole string but lets you match elements in the middle:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s("aaabbbccd123456eeffgg");
    std::smatch match;
    std::regex braced_regex("\\d{2,}"); // just the numbers

    auto printer = [](auto& match) {
            std::ssub_match sub(match);
            std::string match_substring(sub.str());
            std::cout <<  match_substring << '\n';
    };

    std::regex_search(s, match, braced_regex); // NOTE: regex_search()!
    std::cout << "Number of braced matches: " << match.size() << '\n';
    std::for_each(match.begin(), match.end(), printer);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Number of braced matches: 1
123456
```

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
(\\w+)(\\d{2,})(\\w+)
```

`\\w+` matches any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_], so it matches also 1234

to match whole number change `\\w` to [a-zA-Z_], so you will have:

```
std::regex braced_regex("([a-zA-Z_]+)(\\d{2,})(\\w+)");
```